# `gcloud functions deploy` lists all environment variables--can this be prevented?

Tags: environment-variables, google-cloud-functions

We use Google Cloud to deploy our functions through a bash script, in the form of:

```
  gcloud functions deploy $2 \
    --source $uri \
    --trigger-http \
    --region=us-east1
```

Recently, I noticed that this prints out all environment variables, in plain text:

```
==> Deploying <function_name>...
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...done.                                                                                          
availableMemoryMb: 256
entryPoint:  <function_name>
environmentVariables:
  DB_CONNECTION_NAME: <db>
  DB_PASS: <important_password>
  DB_USER:  <important_user>
  ... more sensitive stuff ...
```

Is there any way to not print `environmentVariables`, perhaps by running the command in some non-verbose mode? I tried the `--quiet` and `--verbosity=WARNING` flags but that didn't address the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--no-user-output-enabled` [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--user-output-enabled) to disable the printed output.

In your case, you may modify your script with the following:

```
  gcloud functions deploy $2 \
    --source $uri \
    --trigger-http \
    --region=us-east1 \
    --no-user-output-enabled
```

More details and other gcloud wide flags can be found here: [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/)